# How to persist in a notebook the result of an imported spreadsheet?

Tags: import, persistence

I create data table in my notebook by importing a excel spreadsheet using:

```
s0 = Import["G:\\Meu Drive\\Planilhas\\resultados_analises.\xlsx",{"Data", 3, Range[5, 54], Range[1, 11]}]
```

Then I create others tables subselecting s0 and make a bunch of analysis, plots etc.

I used

```
PersistentValue["s0"] = s0
```

and then delete (or comment) the Import command and the PersistentValue above. Then I saved the notebook, open it again and type:

```
s0 = PersistentValue["s0"]
```

Then save the notebook again such that every time I load the notebook I work with the same s0 that was imported before instead of Importing again.

My question is: The values associated with s0 is persisted in the notebook forever? Can I move the notebook to another computer, por example?

Or there is a better way to persist my data in the notebook such that I can delete (or comment) the import command?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 3):

My usual way of handling this sort of thing is to use `Iconize`. So I would write:

```
s0 = Iconize[
  Import[
    "G:\\Meu Drive\\Planilhas\\resultados_analises.\xlsx",
    {"Data", 3, Range[5, 54], Range[1, 11]}
  ],
  "My Spreadsheet 2021-12-29"
];
```

Then I would highlight everything after the `=` and before `;` and select Evaluation > Evaluate in Place (CMD + ENTER on Mac). Then, I would run the entire cell normally to assign the spreadsheet to `s0`. The second argument ("My Spreadsheet 2021-12-29" here) is optional but useful for giving it a name that you'll recognize in the future.

This creates a small little icon that represents the imported spreadsheet. This icon can be copied and pasted to new notebooks, and after running the above code, either `s0` or the icon itself can be used exactly as you would use `s0` from your original code. The icon is persistent between notebooks, and there's no risk of accidentally re-importing when running, because the import only happens when you first use Evaluate in Place.